# Sort columns by an specific row

Tags: matlab

I'm working with Matlab and I need to sort the columns of a matrix by row. For example, if we have the next matrix

```
1 3 4
1 0 5
3 2 1
```

After ordering it by the last row

```
4 3 1
5 0 1
1 2 3
```

Is there a function that can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
A = [1, 3, 4;1, 0, 5;3, 2,1]
sorted = sortrows(A',3)'
```

For detailed information please type the following in your MATLAB command window.

```
help sortrows
```